# How can it be that a ZIP file contains multiple files with the same name in the same subdirectory?

Tags: compression, zip, archiving

I had been extracting [Free Pascal source code](ftp://ftp.freepascal.org/pub/fpc/snapshot/trunk/source/fpc.zip) into an empty directory using Midnight Commander (under Mac OS X, which does distinguish between lowercase and uppercase AFAIK) and have been asked if I would like to replace a file. I can't remember which file it was as I didn't pay serious attention and I don't know if there were more than one as I have chosen to replace all but I remember the replacement file was exactly the same size as the original so I didn't worry. But I just can't understand how is this possible at all that a second file of exactly same name and placement was found in the same ZIP archive.

Comment: HFS is not case-sensitive by default, it specifically needs to be formatted that way, which I wouldn't do for a boot partition.

Comment: @Tetsujin But is the ZIP format case-sensitive (allowing files with names identical if not the case in the same subdirectory)?

Comment: That I don't know, which is why I couldn't make a full answer, sorry.

Comment: You can repeat the process and tell us the file names. *I can't remember which file it was* is no excuse to write a question with missing information. Voting to close as 'unclear'.

Comment: I just created a Zip file with multiple files that have the same name using Powershell just `Compress-Archive -Path "foo/*/file.txt" -DestinationPath bar.zip ` will both put `foo/a/file.txt` and `foo/b/file.txt` as `file.txt` into the zip...

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is entirely possible according to the ZIP format.  The problem is rather uncommon, because most software that creates ZIP files will choose to update an already-existing file, rather than create a second file.  I'll make this up: perhaps the ZIP file format keeps track of files using an index number, rather than using the filenames to index?  Anyway, as my hazy memory recalls (when I played around with stuff as a teenager, many years ago), if I made a ZIP file of two files, TEXT1 and TEST2, and then used a hex editor to rename TEST2 to TEXT1, then I would have a ZIP file with two files named TEXT1.  It is absolutely not a violation.  The typical behavior of software is to ask about overwriting the existing file when the later file is extracted.

I also think I was able to create the situation with some less odd activities, perhaps when working with multiple filesystems (like HPFS).  Using a filesystem that supports features that ZIP was not designed for might be particularly prone to have things like this happen.

In Windows 95, I think I could force similar things by zipping "C:\Program Files\Something.txt" and "C:\Progra~1\SOMETH~1.TXT"

I don't have an answer for exactly what you did to create such a thing, but the reported results are not surprising to me.  If this is causing any serious problems, you might want to consider a different file format.  .tar is usually considered to be pretty good and preserving filesystem details (particularly on things that are Unix-like).

Answer (score 0):

As patrix has found out (this should really be made an answer, not a question edit making the question ridiculous) there indeed are 2 identical files with the same name written in different cases:

```
pse@Mithos:~/.tmp$ unzip -v fpc.zip | grep -i boyscout.inc
    4747  Defl:N     1607  66%  10-13-14 10:25  8b6e16fd  fpc/packages/libgbafpc/src/gba/BoyScout.inc
    4747  Defl:N     1607  66%  01-04-15 02:01  8b6e16fd  fpc/packages/libgbafpc/src/gba/boyscout.inc
```

and as Tetsujin has noted HFS (the Mac OS X file system) does not allow this by default.